# Limit Upload/Download file size in squid proxy

Tags: proxy, limit, http-proxy, squid

We are trying to limit upload/download file size in the windows server which is behind Squid proxy(installed on centos 7 EC2).

Even though we are using below param in the squid.conf still we are able to upload or download file size greater than 2 MB

```
request_body_max_size 2 MB all #limit upload
reply_body_max_size 2 MB all #limit download
```

Please help to achieve this

Squid Cache: Version 3.5.20